# How to randomly pick element from array without repeating?

Tags: android, arrays, android-studio

I am working on an quiz app. I managed to randomized the questions(from an array) with

```
int position = new Random().nextInt(questions.length);
```

but the questions keep on repeating. How do i make it stop getting when it reaches lets say 10 questions without repeating? Here is my code if it helps:

```
gcfQuiz.setText(questions[position]);

    gcfButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            EditText Answer = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtAns1);
            String finAns = Answer.getText().toString();

            if (finAns==answers[position]){

                correct++;
            }
            position++;
            if (position<questions.length)
            {
                gcfQuiz.setText(questions[position]);

            }else {
                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), gcfResult.class);
                startActivity(in);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Use ArrayList and remove the question after you randomly picked.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a `List` instead, and then remove the element if it is chosen:

```
List<Question> questions = new ArrayList<Question>();
// For Question class, see below.

// Get some random valid index from the list.
int index = new Random().nextInt(questions.size());
// Remove the question from the list and store it into a variable.
Question currQuestion = questions.remove(i);
```

For your information, I assumed the `Question` class looks like this. This approach is generally better than two separate arrays with questions and answers respectively:

```
class Question {

    private String text;
    private String answer;

    public Question(String text, String answer) {
        this.text = text;
        this.answer = answer;
    }

    public boolean isCorrectAnswer(String inputAnswer) {
        return Objects.equals(answer, inputAnswer);
    }
}
```

### Some tips

- I see you are using `==` to compare `String`s. **Never** ever do that. Use `equals()` instead. See [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/513832/507738).
- I see you have a variable named `Answer`. According to the Java Naming Conventions, variables should start with a lowercase character. See [Code Conventions at the Oracle website](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html).
- See above; you could transfer the responsibility of checking whether an answer is correct to the `Question` class, because it holds the answer string. See [An Object Must be Responsible for Itself](http://www.developer.com/java/other/article.php/3507221/Object-Responsibility.htm).

Comment: My questions and answers arrays are all in the same class as the code. Will it be better if it was in a seperate class? Thanks for answering

Comment: Yes, that's the whole [idea of object-oriented programming](https://www.cs.drexel.edu/~introcs/Fa15/notes/06.1_OOP/Advantages.html?CurrentSlide=3), especially encapsulation: you put things that logically belongs to eachother in a class. Each question has a correct answer, and you transfer the responsibility of checking whether the answer is correct or not to the question.

Answer (score 1):

```
    int n=questions.length;
//if n=100 means it give random numb with no duplicate values with in the range 100.
    Random r = new Random();
    Set<Integer> positionvalue = new HashSet<>();
    for(int i = 0; i <n; i++){
            while(true) {
            int number = r.nextInt(n) + 1;
            if (positionvalue.contains(number) == false) {
                positionvalue.add(number);                   
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

positionvalue set have non-repeating random number between your range(n)

Comment: Thanks but in which part do i insert the question? sorry im new to this

Answer (score 1):

Create a list of questions and shuffle it (via [Collections.shuffle()](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle(java.util.List%3C?%3E))) one time to get a random order of questions:

```
List<String> randomQuestionList = new ArrayList<>();
randomQuestionList.addAll(Arrays.asList(questions));
Collections.shuffle(randomQuestionList);
```

Now you have a randomly ordered list of your questions.

**Note** I saw in your code, that you have your answers in a separate array. To make this shuffle solution work for you, you will need to hold question and answers together. The best way to achieve that, would probably be to create a Question class that holds the question and the answers. Then you can shuffle the questions and still have the answers to every question right at hand.

```
class Question {
    String question;
    String[] answers;
}

List<Question> randomQuestionList ...
```

Comment: how do i know if the answer is correct tho? Thanks for answering

Comment: You should know, which of your answers is the correct one :-)  You could add a field to Question class with the index of the correct answer or create an Answer class with a text and a right/wrong flag (this would also handle cases where you can have more than 1 correct answer).

Comment: Note, that you should probably display the answers in a random order as well -- you can again use shuffle() for that :-)

Answer (score 0):

Take two global variables

```
int nextQuestion;
List<Integer> posList;
```

Then initialise it:

```
private void initRandomLogic() {
    nextQuestion = 0;
    posList  = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i=0;i<questions.length;i++)
        posList.add(i);
    Collections.shuffle(posList);
}

private int getRandomPosition() {
    return posList.get(nextQuestion++);
}
```

Hope will help you!